# OSM polyline with markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, polyline

I have some custom polyline on OSM with this code

```
var polyline1 = [
        [44.772142, 17.208980],
        [44.774753, 17.207644],
        [44.773964, 17.199587],
        [44.770823, 17.199207],
        [44.771399, 17.195699],
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < polyline1.length; i++) {
                var polyline = L.polyline(polyline1, {
                    color: 'red'
                }).addTo(map);;
            }
```

I need markers with popup on all this coordinates, this code cannot work with other:

```
for (var i = 0; i < polyline1.length; i++) {
                var marker = L.marker([polyline1[i][1],polyline1[i][2]])
                .bindPopup(polyline1[i][0])
                .addTo(map);
            }
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Please don't add dozens of unrelated tags while omitting the tag for the library you are using - Leaflet.

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing. You seem to be creating a new polyline x the number of elements in the array and adding them all to the map - did you mean to do this?

Comment: In polyline1 i have 5 points. In first function i made 5 markers with popup, now I need to make polyline from first to last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much simpler than you're making it.

```
// Define some custom icons

var icon1 = L.icon(...);
var icon2 = L.icon(...);
var icon3 = L.icon(...);
var icon4 = L.icon(...);
var icon5 = L.icon(...);


var icons = [ icon1, icon2, icon3, icon4, icon5];


// Define the points

var polyline1 = [
        [44.772142, 17.208980],
        [44.774753, 17.207644],
        [44.773964, 17.199587],
        [44.770823, 17.199207],
        [44.771399, 17.195699],
    ];

// Add a marker at each point

polyline1.forEach(function(LatLng, i) {
    L.marker(LatLng, {icon: icons[i]}).addTo(map);
});

// Add a polyline

L.polyline(polyline1, { color: 'red' }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Is it possible in this situation to set custom marker icon?

Comment: Of course, add whatever code you need to the marker -

Comment: But then I need to write code individually for each marker?

Comment: Do you mean a single custom icon for all markers or a different one for each marker?

Comment: I mean different one for each marker. I even tried with popup                 .bindPopup(polyline1[i][0]), but nothing

Comment: Edited with a suggestion

Comment: It's perfect. Thank You very much